# Где можно скачать готовые цветовые схемы для Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: visual-studio, ide, visual-studio-2017, themes

Где можно скачать готовые цветовые схемы для VS 17 ? 
 Может, где нибудь, для плагина ColorThemes есть готовые решения ?

Answer (score 1):

Кроме https://studiostyl.es/ я встречал только Dracula https://draculatheme.com/visual-studio/

На studiostyl подходят темы для Visual Studio 2015.